# Calculating Regression Coefficients for Very Large Observation Matrices

Tags: regression, large-data, matrix

I am trying to run a regression from a 11300x21500 observation matrix (where there are 11300 observations and 21500 independent variables). However, when I try to implement the usual  $(X^T X)^{-1}$ formula in C++, I can't even initialize the observation matrix $X$ due to memory limitations (The application closes itself when the memory usage is around 1 GB. I have 8 GB memory but I think there is an OS command to limit memory usage of each application).

Is there any other technique which is more suitable for such a regression? Can there be any way to overcome this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Big or small, one should (almost) *never* compute regression coefficients by inverting $X^T X$. Use a stable QR decomposition algorithm. (But this doesn't answer your *real* question.)

Comment: Also: $11300 \cdot 21500 \cdot 8 = 1\,943\,600\,000$, so even the most compact of storage is going to take up 2GB of memory just to store the matrix. And, anyway, there is no way that $X^T X$ is invertible in the first place if you have 11K observations and 21K features.

Comment: @cardinal Before now, I was mainly working on other parts of my algorithm, and tried to avoid the invertability issue by adding small value(0.000000001) to the diagonal values of the $X^TX$ to produce a matrix that is close to the original one. But I didn't really thought on its possible objectionable consequences. I think I can find a way to work with 2GB data. But this is the first time I heard about QR decomp. Could you elaborate its usage in regressions? This isn't really my strong point. By the way, most of the columns in each row is 0 in the data.Can I take advantage of that with memory?

Comment: To deal with the memory limit:  open Task Manager...Processes...R-click on your stat program...Set Priority...High.

Comment: @rolando2: What OS is that?

Comment: @rolando2 Thanks, I didn't know that! It's Windows 7 btw

Comment: @cardinal Could you detail how to use QR decomp for regression by the way, it would be most helpful!

Comment: "anyway, there is no way that $X^TX$ is invertible in the first place if you have 11K observations and 21K features" is an important comment by @cardinal - when the number of parameters is greater than the sample size, there is no unique solution - you will need do some kind of regularization (e.g. imposing 'sparsity' of the solution, indicating that many of the regression coefficients are exactly '0') to get coefficient estimates. Imposing sparsity in this context is a very active area of research, where Lasso-type penalties are used on the regression coefficients.

Comment: I would certainly echo the concerns above - you need a well-defined statistical question before someone can pose an answer in the first place.  If after this you are still memory limited, there are some straight-forward ways to work around this.  You might consider an EC2 large-memory instance.  R users might see [this post](http://inundata.org/2011/03/30/r-ec2-rstudio-server/) to set this up with an interactive interface.